# Basic string slicing from indices

Tags: string, indices, program-slicing

I will state the obvious that I am a beginner. I should also mention that I have been coding in Zybooks, which affects things. My textbook hasn't helped me much

I tried sub_lyric= rhyme_lyric[ : ]

Zybooks should be able to input an index number can get only that part of the sentence but my book doesnt explain how to do that. If it throws a [4:7] then it would output cow. Hopefully I have exolained everything well.

[image: a screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set there:

```
sub_lyric = rhyme_lyric[start_index:end_index]
```

The string is as a sequence of characters and you can use *string slicing* to extract any sub-text from the main one. As you have observed:

```
sub_lyric = rhyme_lyric[:]
```

will copy the entire content of `rhyme_lyric` to `sub_lyric`.

To select only a portion of the text, specify the `start_index` (strings start with index 0) to `end_index` (not included).

```
sub_lyric = rhyme_lyric[4:7]
```

will extract characters in `rhyme_lyric` from position 4 (included) to position 7 (not included) so the result will be `cow`.

You can check more on *string slicing* here: [Python 3 introduction](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html)

Comment: Thankyou sir! Can't believe I din't think of that. Appreciated.